# Angular: How to include service in feature module

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-services, angular-module

After creating new module for my feature modules and separating their route paths from the app.module.ts I'm getting the error of,

```
    core.js:6185 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[LoginService -> HttpClient -> HttpClient -> HttpClient]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpClient!
NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[LoginService -> HttpClient -> HttpClient -> HttpClient]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for HttpClient!
    at NullInjector.get (core.js:1076)
    at R3Injector.get (core.js:16629)
    at R3Injector.get (core.js:16629)
    at R3Injector.get (core.js:16629)
    at injectInjectorOnly (core.js:931)
    at Module.ɵɵinject (core.js:941)
    at Object.LoginService_Factory [as factory] (login.service.ts:10)
    at R3Injector.hydrate (core.js:16865)
    at R3Injector.get (core.js:16617)
    at NgModuleRef$1.get (core.js:36027)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:798)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:750)
    at zone-evergreen.js:860
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:399)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:41264)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:398)
    at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:167)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone-evergreen.js:569)
    at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone-evergreen.js:484)
    at invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:1621)
```

I am creating a simple login service. From a welcome page once user clicks the "play" button the login page will arrive. However, whenever I'm clicking the respective button I'm getting the above error. And this seems like started arriving after I separated the login feature in a feature module. However, my service has injector defined as,

```
@Injectable({
providedIn:'root'
```

})

So this means only one instance of service will be created and will be shared in entire APP. However, I'm now doubtful. Do, I need to declare my service somewhere in my feature module ? I have correctly imported,

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
```

in my app.module.ts. Here is my app.module.ts,

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
//import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';


import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { WelcomeComponent } from './home/welcome.component';
import { ActivityComponent } from './shared_component/activitiy-progress.component';
import { SmartWatchComponent } from './smart-watch/smart-watch.component';
import { SmartPhoneComponent } from './smart-phone/smart-phone.component';
import { SmartPhoneMenuComponent } from './smart-phone-menu/smart-phone-menu.component';
import { GameStartComponent } from './game-start/game-start.component';
//import { UserLoginComponent } from './user-login/user-login.component';
import { PageNotfoundComponent } from './page-notfound/page-notfound.component';
import { ResetPasswordComponent } from './reset-password/reset-password.component';
import { UserSignupComponent } from './user-signup/user-signup.component';
import { UserCalendarComponent } from './user-calendar/user-calendar.component';
import { UserNewsComponent } from './user-news/user-news.component';
import { UserStorageComponent } from './user-storage/user-storage.component';
import { TodoListComponent } from './todo-list/todo-list.component';
import { AuthenticationModule } from './authentication/authentication.module';
import { LoginService } from './login.service';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    WelcomeComponent,
    ActivityComponent,
    SmartWatchComponent,
    SmartPhoneComponent,
    SmartPhoneMenuComponent,
    GameStartComponent,
    PageNotfoundComponent,
    //ResetPasswordComponent,
    //UserLoginComponent,
    //UserSignupComponent,
    UserCalendarComponent,
    UserNewsComponent,
    UserStorageComponent,
    TodoListComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    AuthenticationModule,
    AppRoutingModule

  ],
 // providers: [LoginService],
 providers : [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Here is my feature module,

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import {RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
import { FormsModule,ReactiveFormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';
import { UserLoginComponent } from '../user-login/user-login.component';
import { UserSignupComponent } from '../user-signup/user-signup.component';
import { ResetPasswordComponent } from '../reset-password/reset-password.component';


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([
      {path:'login',component: UserLoginComponent},
      {path:'signup',component: UserSignupComponent},
      {path:'reset-password',component: ResetPasswordComponent},
     // {path:'',redirectTo:'login',pathMatch:'full'}
    ]),
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    UserLoginComponent,
    UserSignupComponent,
    ResetPasswordComponent
  ],

})
export class AuthenticationModule { }
```

Here is the service,

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient,HttpErrorResponse} from '@Angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import{map,catchError} from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})

export class LoginService {

  private loginUrl : string;
  constructor(private http:HttpClient){}



  getCurrentUserInfo(loginInfo) : Observable<any>{

    this.loginUrl = <my-url>; //for privacy I had to omit the URL
    console.log("this.loginUrl =", this.loginUrl);
    return this.http.get<any>(this.loginUrl)
    .pipe(map(response => response as any),
    catchError(this.handleError));
  }

  private handleError(err:HttpErrorResponse){
    let errorMessage = '';
    if(err.error instanceof ErrorEvent){
        errorMessage = `An error has occurred ${err.error.message}`;
    }else{
        errorMessage = `server returned code: ${err.status}, error message is: ${err.message} `;
    }

    console.error(errorMessage);
    return throwError(errorMessage);

   }
}
```

here is my login component,

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { LoginService } from '../login.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-login',
  templateUrl: './user-login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-login.component.css']
})
export class UserLoginComponent{
  testId = "testuser";
  testPwd = "pwd";
  userLoginForm = new FormGroup({
    userId : new FormControl(''),
    password : new FormControl('')

  });

constructor(private loginService : LoginService, private router : Router){}

  onLoginSubmit(){

    let loginInfo = {
      id : this.userLoginForm.value.userId,
      password : this.userLoginForm.value.password

    }

    if(loginInfo.id === "" || loginInfo.password === ""){
      alert("Please enter Id & passowrd");
    }else if(loginInfo.id === this.testId){
      if(loginInfo.password === this.testPwd){
        this.router.navigate(['/game-start']);
      }else{
        alert("password doesn't exist");
        this.router.navigate(['/reset-password']);
      }
    }else{
      alert("userId doesn't exist");
    }





    this.loginService.getCurrentUserInfo(loginInfo).subscribe({
      next : data => console.log("returned data : " , data)
    });

  }


}
```

Here is my welcome component. Whenever it is navigating to the login page, the error is occurring.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
@Component({
  selector : 'welcome',
  templateUrl: './welcome.component.html',
  styleUrls : ['./welcome.component.css']
})
export class WelcomeComponent {
  public pageTitle = 'SurvCovid App';
  submitted = false;
  constructor(private router: Router){}

  onSubmit(){
    this.submitted = true;
    this.processInitialServerCommunitaion();
  }

  processInitialServerCommunitaion(){
    //this.ngZone.run(() => this.router.navigate(['/app-start']))
    //this.router.navigate(['/game-start'], {state: {"Test":"test"}});
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
   //alert('from game start');
  }
}
```

Here is my app routing module,

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
import { UserCalendarComponent } from './user-calendar/user-calendar.component';
import { UserNewsComponent } from './user-news/user-news.component';
import { UserStorageComponent } from './user-storage/user-storage.component';
import { TodoListComponent } from './todo-list/todo-list.component';
import { SmartPhoneMenuComponent } from './smart-phone-menu/smart-phone-menu.component';
import { GameStartComponent } from './game-start/game-start.component';
//import { ResetPasswordComponent } from './reset-password/reset-password.component';
import { PageNotfoundComponent } from './page-notfound/page-notfound.component';
import { WelcomeComponent } from './home/welcome.component';

const ROUTES = [
    //{path:'login',component: UserLoginComponent},
   // {path:'signup',component: UserSignupComponent},
    {path:'welcome',component: WelcomeComponent},
    {path:'calendar',component: UserCalendarComponent},
    {path: 'news',component:UserNewsComponent},
    {path: 'storage',component:UserStorageComponent},
    {path: 'todo-list',component:TodoListComponent},
    {path : 'smartPhone-menu',component:SmartPhoneMenuComponent},
    {path : 'game-start',component :GameStartComponent},
    {path:'',redirectTo:'welcome',pathMatch:'full'},
   // {path:'reset-password',component: ResetPasswordComponent},
    {path : '**',component : PageNotfoundComponent}
    /*{path:'**',redirectTo:'welcome', pathMatch: 'full'}*/
  ];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES)
    ],
    exports : [RouterModule]
})

export class AppRoutingModule{}
```

Here is the versions I'm using,

```
Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.900.7
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.900.7
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.900.7
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.900.7
@angular-devkit/core              9.0.7
@angular-devkit/schematics        9.0.7
@ngtools/webpack                  9.0.7
@schematics/angular               9.0.7
@schematics/update                0.900.7
rxjs                              6.5.4
typescript                        3.7.5
webpack                           4.41.2
```

I'm learning Angular and quite lost with this problem. I searched the solution in similar stakoverflow posts but mostly everyone suggested to import HttpClientModule which I already did. And also, it seems nobody faced this while routing/loading a component while loading the service. That's why I feel this is a new problem. Any help therefore would be very much appreciated.

Comment: So did you try adding the HttpclientModule in your feature module..?

Comment: Thank you. Yes I tried that but no help.

Comment: Any ‘other’ code, maybe an app-Initializer or interceptor that uses loginService?

Comment: @MikeOne : How does it help ? could you please elaborate ?

Comment: I’m not sure. What you have looks fine so I’m thinking that maybe there is somewhere else in your code that uses the loginService while httpModule is not available.. like a factory where you might have to provide the client manually.

Comment: Not really. This loginService is used only in the login component currently. However, as you mentioned about the httpModule, I'm also getting a warning https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61423410/angular-error-multiple-modules-with-names-that-only-differ-in-casing . Since, I was getting that warning that's why I tried to separate my feature module from app module and now ended up in this error.

Comment: @sandy Did you find the solution? I have that same problem...

Answer (score 0):

You can specify that the service should be provided in the module by changing `providedIn` value.

Replace

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
```

With:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: AuthenticationModule,
})
```

Read this [article](https://angular.io/guide/providers) for more deatails

Comment: THanks for offering help. However this gives me error "authentication.module.ts:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'AuthenticationModule' before initialization
    at Module.AuthenticationModule (authentication.module.ts:1)
    at Module../src/app/login.service.ts "

Answer (score 0):

On your feature module, declare the provider as

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([
      {path:'login',component: UserLoginComponent},
      {path:'signup',component: UserSignupComponent},
      {path:'reset-password',component: ResetPasswordComponent},
     // {path:'',redirectTo:'login',pathMatch:'full'}
    ]),
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    UserLoginComponent,
    UserSignupComponent,
    ResetPasswordComponent
  ],
  providers:[LoginService]
})
```

Comment: Thank you that you tried to help but it didn't work in this case unfortunately.

Comment: can you post the `AppRoutingModule` aswell.

Comment: Just added AppRoutingModule

Comment: Your application default routes to `WelcomeComponent` which is a part of your `AppModule`, and thereafter your route to `this.router.navigate(['/login']);` from the WelcomeComponent, but in your app-routing module, a path for login `login` is not defined.

What you can do is lazyload your feature module from the app module. And thereby load the LoginComponent.

[Lazy Loading in Angular](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules)

Comment: THat's a nice suggestion. did that. In the authetication module I did , RouterModule.forChild([
      {path:'',component: UserLoginComponent},

and app routing module I did,
{
    path:'login',
    loadChildren: () => import('./authentication/authentication.module').then(m => m.AuthenticationModule)
    },

But no Luck !!!!

Comment: did you try this ` providers:[LoginService]` now?

Comment: yes.butno help. import { LoginService } from '../login.service';
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([
      {path:'',component: UserLoginComponent},
      {path:'signup',component: UserSignupComponent},
      {path:'reset-password',component: ResetPasswordComponent},
     // {path:'',redirectTo:'login',pathMatch:'full'}
    ]),
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    UserLoginComponent,
    UserSignupComponent,
    ResetPasswordComponent
  ],
  providers:[LoginService]
  
})
export class AuthenticationModule { }

Answer (score 0):

You can use @Injectable({ providedIn:'**any**' }) which means all eagerly loaded modules share a singleton instance; however, lazy loaded modules each get their own unique instance.

If you are using @Injectable({ providedIn:'**root**' }), specify the providers:[LoginService] in your feature module.

Answer (score 0):

seems wrong import statement in service file please try updating below and check once

```
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from '@Angular/common/http';
```

to

```
import {HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
```

( `@angular` is lowercased )